# Conflicting Framework names -- Crashlytics + Fabric

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

My app crashes whenever I try to build it. It crashes specifically when I change the iOS platform on the Cocoapods. When the Cocoapods platform is iOS 7, I run into no build problems, when I edit the platform to 8.0 I get a build error that tell me there's conflicting frameworks. Specifically the crashlytics and Fabric framework.  I can't downgrade cocoapods (unfortunately) so I Was hopging someone could advise me with another to go about this. Please not that I'm not using any swift fraemworks.

Comment: crashlytics is a part of fabric, not sure why you are including both

Comment: Neither am I. I'm just a lowly mid though. I don't question the principles out of feeeeeear.

Comment: I did a google search and came upon this http://db42.in/2015/02/15/duplicate-symbols-crashlytics/  maybe it will help

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. 

It's odd the conflict is happening only when changing iOS platforms. What's your pod spec look like?

You should have:

pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

Full details here: https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/cocoapods.html